# How do I programmatically convert FLV video files to MP4 using a shell script in OS X?

Tags: macos, unix, shell, video-processing, transcoding

I want to batch convert a directory containing hundreds of FLV files so that each file has a MP4 equivalent. I'm trying to automate this process by writing a shell script and running it from the Terminal. How do I go about doing that? Most of the instructions available are for Linux using ffmpeg but I think OS X doesn't have it. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can install ffmpeg via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). The commnd to install ffmpeg with Homebrew is `brew install ffmpeg`; similarly, the command to install ffmpeg with MacPorts is `sudo port install ffmpeg`. Once you've installed ffmpeg, here is a simple (and somewhat naive) script for converting the files. You may need to add more flags, depending on your desired  options.

```
#! /bin/bash
function convert_all_to_mp4() {
  for file in *.flv ; do
    local bname=$(basename "$file" .flv)
    local mp4name="$bname.mp4"
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "$mp4name"
  done
}
convert_all_to_mp4
```

Just make whatever file you put the script above in executable (for example, `chmod a+x path/to/convert_all_to_mp4.sh`) and invoke it by its fully qualified path or add the directory containing it to the PATH environment varaible and invoke the script by the name you gave it.

Comment: This code has great potential. Will try it out. I can imagine so many uses for it other than this task. Thanks. ;-)

Comment: hello, i am new in this field,Please help me , where need to add this script and how to call this script on button click event

Comment: @avi, I've updated the answer to include a few more details about how to invoke the script. However, the basics of BASH is a bit beyond the scope of the question. You can find other information on StackOverflow about how to invoke BASH scripts and manipulate the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 10):

### Conversion from FLV to MP4 using ffmpeg

**Aim:** Convert multiple Adobe Flash Video (FLV) files to MP4 using a Bash script.

**My Environment:**
MAC OS X 10.5.8, Terminal v.240.2, Bash v.3.2.17 (This solution should work with most Apple Mac systems).

**Language:**
bash

**Description:**
This script will search for all FLV files in the specified location, iterate through each one, converting them to an equivalent MP4 video and place them in the sub-directory *MP4-yymmdd-HHMMSS*.   Log files generated during the process are placed in the *log* directory within this sub-directory.

**Prerequisites:**
Download the ffmpeg binary and place in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.
My code is based on Jan's blog on trick77.com.  See "References" for details.
Download my bash script from the "Bash Script" section.

**Explanation of my code**

- Copy any MP4 files present

  Detect the video codec type using `ffmpeg -i [file]`.

  Cycle through each video and convert according to the type of video codec used.

  Concatenate all the ffmpeg log files

**Limitations:**
Only processes videos with the FLV1 and H264 codecs.

**Usage:**

```
convert-flv-to-mp4.sh [folder path]
```

**Example:**

```
./convert-flv-to-mp4.sh /Users/Shared/Music
```

**Output:**
mp4 files in the *MP4-yymmdd-HHMMSS* subdirectory

**Logs:**
convert-flv-to-mp4.log.txt                  - program log
ffmpeg-yyyymmdd-HHMMSS.log.txt - ffmpeg binary log for each file converted
ffmpeg.log.txt                                    - compilation of all the above ffmpeg logs
metadata.csv                                    - metadata for each video file

**Discussion:**
In my first attempt, I was not able to convert videos with the FLV1 video stream using the `-copy` ffmpeg option. Instead, I needed to use the following ffmpeg options:

`-strict experimental -b:a 64k`

This means that the conversion doesn't halt on minor errors and that it uses 64k audio bit rate conversion.

Using the `-copy` option just remuxes the input video and hence is fast.  Otherwise, ffmpeg will transcode the file, which takes considerably longer.  This script will determine which option to use.

**Key snippet of code:**

```
ls ${inputdir}/*.flv>$inputlist
for i in $(cat $inputlist); do
    ...
    case $vtype in
        flv1)
            ffmpeg -report -v info -nostdin -fflags discardcorrupt -i $i -strict experimental -c:v mpeg4 -b:a 64k ${outputdir}/${basename}.mp4 
        h264)
            ffmpeg -report -v verbose -nostdin -fflags discardcorrupt -i $i -vcodec copy -acodec copy ${outputdir}/${basename}.mp4
    esac
    ...
done
```

***where:***

> inputlist - file containing all the FLV files
>  
>   vtype    - the video codec type of the input file
>   i            - the input FLV filename

**Example log file:**

[image: Example log file]

**Metadata log file:**
[image: Metadata extracted from video using ffmpeg]

**Conclusion:**
A complete solution was successfully tested on 73 FLV files downloaded from youtube.  It took 8 minutes to transcode 34 files and remux 39 files, on average 11MB in size.

**Bash Script:**
[convert-flv-to-mp4.sh](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BykVWnOzAgFVT2NFNXRObDVZTjA)

**References:**
[FFmpeg Binary Download](http://ffmpegmac.net/)
[FFmpeg Official Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)
[How to convert .flv Flash video to .mp4 on the Mac](http://trick77.com/2010/11/22/how-to-convert-flv-flash-video-to-mp4-on-the-mac/)

**Extensibility:**
If you have any FLV files that have a video stream other than FLV1 or H264, e.g. VP6, FLV4, add a comment with a link to your video file and I will update my code to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s nocaseglob
for file in *.flv
do
  ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%flv}mp4"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with VLC

http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode#Transcoding_with_the_Command_Prompt

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-mac.html) which has a really good batch function.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -iname "*.flv" -exec ffmpeg -nostdin -fflags discardcorrupt -i "{}" -strict experimental -c:v mpeg4 -b:a 192k "{}.mp4"  \;
```

Comment: Hi, here are some guidelines for your answer: It is **not recommended** to post code-only answers, consider to also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.